# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Please suggest some **hint** to test the convergence of the following series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)$$

Comment: Do you have the [Leibniz criterion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizCriterion.html) at your disposal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Oh No ... then $\lim (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = \lim\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=0$ and $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\ge \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}.$ Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We have 
$$u_n=(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$
So the sequence $(|u_n|)_n$ converges to $0$ and is monotone decreasing then by [Alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series) the series $\sum_n u_n$ is convergent.